# Using an exported service in another app on Android

Tags: android, service

I have a main app that includes a service and a second app that wants to make use of that service.

The main app has this in the manifest (not inside an activity):

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.foo.XMPPService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:process="xmppService" />
```

In the second app I try to bind to it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.example.foo", "com.example.foo.XMPPService");
bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

But I get the error:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app2/com.example.app2.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { cmp=com.example.foo/.XMPPService }
```

So I'm wondering why this is not allowed, while I set "exported" to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start `android:process` with a lowercase letter, from the documentation:

`If the process name begins with a lowercase character, the service will run in a global process of that name, provided that it has permission to do so. This allows components in different applications to share a process, reducing resource usage.`

The service will be part of your application if you would leave this tag alone. As soon as you start messing with it, it will create a process for itself. This global process will be run as system user and requires to be signed with a platform certificate.

Comment: Ah, I interpret that text the wrong way. Tried `android:process="XMPPService"` and removing it, but still the same problem. Any suggestion on how to do it correctly?